# Data path "['build']" should have required property 'builder'

Tags: angular7, angular-library, angularbuild

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "['build']" should have required property 'builder'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "['build']" should have required property 'builder'.

Answer (score 0):

Add below in `angular.json` under main project schema.

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
       ...
 }
```